# Is a 'peeve' the same thing as a 'gripe'?

Tags: american-english

Many times on this site have I heard something described as a 'peeve'. My sense is that this is American.

Although the verb, usually in the passive - *he was peeved because he had been given the wrong change, and refused to visit the shop again -* exists in Britain, I have seldom heard it used as a noun.

The usual term in Britain I would have said was a 'gripe'. Is a 'peeve' the same thing as a 'gripe'?

Nonetheless I think both expressions are over-the-top for the examples which sometimes appear here. I would tend to call most of them 'pet dislikes'. I think 'peeve' or 'gripe' places too strong a negative sense upon them. A normal healthy mind has likes and dislikes. Dislikes do not have to be justified. In most English-speaking lands people are free to state their preferences.

Comment: A _peeve_ is a frequently-felt irritation. Many people cherish them, whence the phrase _my pet peeve_. In the context of language use, a peeve refers to a habit of others' speech (never of one's own speech) that someone finds irritating. Such habits are always incorrectly perceived (see "zombie rules"), but that never seems to assuage the peeve itself, which is lovingly trotted out at every opportunity. The common term for the activity of language peeving (and its result) is _peevage_, the agentive form is _peever_, and the mass term for peevers is the _Peeververein_.

Comment: @JohnLawler 'Peeve' is actually a stronger word than would normally be used in Britain for this. At least that is my sense. I would be interested to hear what others think. Sometimes people will talk about their 'pet hates'. 'Hate' is also a strong word. But it doesn't (to me) carry any implied sense that you would like to 'get even' with the thing that is peeving you. As someone once observed, we are two nations separated by a common language.

Comment: I find _peeve_ to be a very weak word, in the sense that a _peeve_ is something that you dislike but it's so stupid a thing to dislike that it's verging on an OCD type behaviour; like getting annoyed when someone puts fruit in the vegetable drawer of the fridge or stands an upside-down ketchup bottle right-way up. Even weaker (but more persistent) than a _whinge_ and a lot less rational.

Comment: @Frank In a sense you make my point for me. So if someone says one of my posts is a 'peeve', are they thinking that I suffer from OCD?

Comment: If you call someone "peevish", aren't you saying that they are someone who gets annoyed by minor issues?  So if that is true, how can a "peeve" be too strong of a word?

Comment: @KristinaLopez Because it is quite unkind to accuse someone of 'getting annoyed over a minor issue'. To the person complaining it may not be a minor issue, in which case you are using too strong a word.

Comment: Ah.. I see what you mean. Then yes, suggesting you are peevish suggests that you are _of a disposition to be vexed at trifles_ and that's the nicest one I can find readily. Perverse, foolish, mad & spiteful are all somewhat less 'lyrical'. Peeve(ish) is taking on a slightly different tone now. OK when one applies it to oneself, somewhat nasty applying it to others.

Comment: @Frank Yes, people do have likes and dislikes. My father who died recently, three months short of his 100th birthday, would never eat mutton. There was no logical reason, he ate all other meats that Englishmen eat. But I wouldn't dream of regarding his indisposition to mutton, a 'peeve' of any description.

Comment: I wouldn't class that as a _peeve_, it's the _vexation at trifles_ that turns a dislike into a peeve. I don't eat (nor ever have eaten) prawns, it's not a peeve, gripe, whinge, grumble, moan or complaint; I just don't feel the need to eat prawns when there's cows to be eaten.

Comment: @WS2 I'm not denying that it's unkind, but that doesn't make it any less true if someone is characteristically annoyed by what others may consider "minor" issues.  FWIW, in my culture, (AmE, Midwest region), it's common to say about ourselves, "that's a pet peeve of mine".  If someone else called my posting "a peeve", I guess I'd have two choices, own it or deny it.  But if it walks like a duck... :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez It has been suggested by KitFox that peeving can *also encompass raging, ranting, eye rolling, snarking, and some types of trolling like flamebaiting*. If you are doing a lot of that over minor issues I'm seriously quite worried about you.

Comment: @Frank Unless you have been living on hamburgers I think it unlikely you have been eating 'cows'. We get milk from cows, and when they are no good for that they grind them up for hamburgers. As a country boy I understood what castration was at a very young age. I hope what you have been eating have been 'bullocks'.

Comment: @WS2, I didn't see any cited source that peeving can include ranting and raging, etc.  Again, *in my culture*, peeving is complaining about relatively minor issues, like someone habitually leaving the toilet lid up.  I don't deny that an unresolved peeve *may* eventually evolve into a full rant or even a rage (when the proverbial camel's back has been broken), but they are distinctively different.  (Thanks for worrying about me! lol!)

Comment: I'm not in the UK - things is different. Our cows don't do milk, they just do more cows; so they only get eaten when they stop producing. It's not so bad, an 8hr soak in papaya juice and a soak in couple of bottles of beer for me and I can imagine it's Kobe. Maybe I should take that up as a pet peeve 'Why can't I buy veal?' I think that's more of a gripe than a peeve.

Comment: @Frank I used to live in Japan myself, 40 years ago. I always suspected the milk didn't come out of cows, it had such an odd taste!

Answer (score 4):

John Lawler illustrates *peeve* nicely. Per his comment:

> A peeve is a frequently-felt irritation. Many people cherish them, whence the phrase my pet peeve. In the context of language use, a peeve refers to a habit of others' speech (never of one's own speech) that someone finds irritating. Such habits are always incorrectly perceived (see "zombie rules"), but that never seems to assuage the peeve itself, which is lovingly trotted out at every opportunity.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/peeve) suggests that it is an American backformation from *peevish*. Merriam-Webster suggests *nark* as a British synonym for peeve, but I can't attest to that.

On the other hand, a *gripe* is a grumbling complaint. [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gripe) shows that this is a much older word. *Gripe* is not particular to British or American English.

These two things are not the same, but they are related. A person may enjoy griping about their favored peeve, for instance. In that case, *peeving* and *griping* can overlap. However, *peeving* can also encompass raging, ranting, eye rolling, snarking, and some types of trolling like flamebaiting. None of these behaviors would be considered *griping*.

FumbleFingers adds the very important note that *peeving* includes an implied appeal to authority, whereas *griping* does not. For instance:

> It should be 'ten items or *fewer*'. That's the rule!

is peeving. Compare this with:

> They put the sign in the middle of the aisle, and I crashed right into it. I'm always crashing into things at that store. It's like they don't know how to lay out traffic patterns.

is more like griping.

Comment: OED2 says _gripe_ is American (1930's). _gripe_ as a complaint isn't in OED1. Dictionary.com are talking about _gripe_ meaning _grip_ in the older senses. Peeve (or at least Peevish) is old - 1300's - but _peeve_ is 20th century.

Comment: Aren't 'raging, ranting, eye rolling, snarking (not much used in UK), and flamebaiting', rather strong stuff? If someone here accuses me of 'peeving', are these the sorts of things they imagine I'm doing?

Comment: I'd also add that *peeving* invariably includes an element of claiming one's position is "correct" according to some higher/objective authority (perhaps simply "logic"). Whereas *griping* can be simply moaning about something you don't like, or that inconveniences you (regardless of any rights and wrongs).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I accept the difference in meaning with 'gripe'. But wouldn't you agree that 'peeving' is a slightly stronger word than we would normally use for what happens on the site? Am I the only one who thinks this?

Comment: @WS2: I don't really think "stronger/weaker" is particularly relevant to *peeving, griping, moaning, complaining, grouching, grousing, grumbling,* etc. To me, the primary difference between peeving and all the others is the "appeal to a higher authority" as already mentioned. And the fact that *to peeve* invariably means to criticise what someone else does (*especially* in matters of language use), in contexts where by implication whoever accuses you of peeving does *not* accept whatever "authority" you're appealing to for backup. You can gripe about having "bad luck", but not peeve about it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But I sense they are all things which a gentleman doesn't do.

Comment: ...and on ELU it's pretty much standard practice to dismiss certain questions as "peeves" if the OP appears to only be asking something here because he dislikes some common usage, and wants *us* to back him up by agreeing that whatever bothers him is in fact "incorrect", that people shouldn't do it, and that he's in the right when he takes issue with them.

Comment: @WS2 It *can* include those actions, but doesn't necessarily so. *Peeving* can get heated, but is often simply grumbly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree, when people 'out' their peeves they do seem to be looking for others to justify their peeve and make into a valid complaint. Like eating a Kit-Kat by simply biting across all four lengths and not breaking off a length and nibbling it.

Comment: @Frank: That's my pet peeve of all time! I can't *stand* people who bite all the way across the KitKat! I know they only do it so if I ask for a stick they'll say *"Too late! I've already started eating them all"*. Worse than people in the pub who leave a note on their beer when they go for a piss, saying *"Don't drink my beer - I spat in it"*. Worse even than the people who leave another note saying *"So did I!"*. Worse even than the ones who say *"I **pissed** in my beer!"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Remind us never to go out for a pint after visiting a confectioners. (too chatty I know)

Comment: @KitFox, I think peeving is a *gateway* to arguing and escalated hostilities but not synonymous with more heated disagreements - IMO, of course! :-)

Answer (score 0):

One does not necessarily express a 'peeve', and in fact one may be likely to act out ones annoyance instead.  That is one way of being 'peevish'.  A 'gripe' is something expressed.

Comment: I don't know, I think one can "*have* a gripe", yet not express it. That's why you can literally say "I have a gripe with you."; *before you said those words*, you still had the gripe.

Comment: I don't think so.  Griping is an actual expression.  You can have a gripe that you need to make, and not yet have gotten to making it, but if you never do, it wasn't griping.  I can have a word for you as well, but, if I do not get to deliver it, it is not really a word.

Comment: Of course the verb "*to gripe"* (and the gerund "*griping*"), as a verb, requires action. But the noun "*a gripe*", an inert object, does not.  Similarly for [gripe's synonyms](http://i.word.com/idictionary/gripe), "*complaint*" and "*grievance*"; one must act to *complain*; but can have a *complaint* without acting (cf *grieve* vs *grievance*). You may have *a word* for me; but I have a *bone to pick* with you, which remains, as yet, unpicked.

Comment: OK, but the intention is to express it.  The intention when peeved is often passive-aggressive non-expression.  Griping people are actively annoying.  Peevish people are passively touchy instead.

Comment: If I have a peeve and I think you should hear about it, I'll say, "that's one of my peeves" or "that's a pet peeve of mine" (a very idiomatic phrase in my part of the world).

Comment: But it is seldom at the point where you are peeved that you will say that.  You are avoiding future temptations to be passive-aggressive by airing the issue, so that you will not become peevish.